# Docker image build failure - wget

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions

I have a docker file in which I do wget to copy something in the image. But the build is failing giving 'wget command not found'. WHen i googled I found suggestions to install wget like below

```
RUN apt update && apt upgrade
RUN apt install wget
```

### Docker File:

```
FROM openjdk:17
LABEL maintainer="app"
ARG  uname
ARG  pwd

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash -u 1000 user1

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN ./gradlew build -PmavenUsername=$uname -PmavenPassword=$pwd

ARG YOURKIT_VERSION=2021.11
ARG POLARIS_YK_DIR=YourKit-JavaProfiler-2019.8
RUN wget https://www.yourkit.com/download/docker/YourKit-JavaProfiler-${YOURKIT_VERSION}-docker.zip --no-check-certificate -P /tmp/ && \
  unzip /tmp/YourKit-JavaProfiler-${YOURKIT_VERSION}-docker.zip -d /usr/local && \
  mv /usr/local/YourKit-JavaProfiler-${YOURKIT_VERSION} /usr/local/$POLARIS_YK_DIR && \
  rm /tmp/YourKit-JavaProfiler-${YOURKIT_VERSION}-docker.zip


EXPOSE 10001
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 5005

USER 1000

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/docker_entrypoint.sh"]
```

On doing this I am getting error app-get not found. Can some one suggest any solution.

Comment: Please share dockerfile, probably you are using image with different package manager than apt (for example centos with yum)

Comment: I added the docker file cotent. Please have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The openjdk image you use is based on Oracle Linux which uses microdnf rather than apt as it's package manager.

To install wget (and unzip which you also need), you can add this to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN microdnf update \
 && microdnf install --nodocs wget unzip \
 && microdnf clean all \
 && rm -rf /var/cache/yum
```

The commands clean up the package cache after installing, to keep the image size as small as possible.